# Pytesseract converting to wrong strings

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm currently using pytesseract and cv2 to try to read this Health Bar.

[image]

The only problem is that when I try to convert it to a string using `pytesseract.image_to_string(img)`, it recognizes this line before the number 1 as 1 itself, so the returned value is : `11189/10180`

Any thoughts on how can I work around this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If the image is constant, you can crop it. Or you can just exclude the first "1" if it is always there. Alternatively you can play with preprocessing the image...

Answer (score 1):

If you apply [OTSU's threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

[image]

The OCR result is:

```
| 1189 / 10180
```

if you don't want `|` and `/`, you can use `isalnum()` but this time result will be:

```
118910180
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("glwMK.png")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thr))

# Display
cv2.imshow("", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```